# C++ pass const char* pointer array to object

Tags: c++, string, parameter-passing

Dear StackOverFlowers,

I'm having trouble passing a `const char* []` to an object. The scenario is as follows.

I have a `class UlamScreen` which contains a `const char* []` with several strings. `UlamScreen` also contains an object `homeScreenMenu`.

```
class UlamScreen {
  const char* homeScreenText[5] = {"EVA dun", "Sabine", "TPU dun", "test Wout", 
  UlamScreenMenu homeScreenMenu;
};

class UlamScreenMenu {    
private:
  const char* _menuText[];

public:
  UlamScreenMenu(const char*[]);
  void drawMenu();
};
```

I want to pass the `const char* []` to `UlamScreenMenu` so I can use it in a member function called `void drawMenu`, like this:

```
void UlamScreenMenu::drawMenu() {
  for (int i = 0; i < menuItems; i++) {
      tft.println(_menuText[i]);
  }
}
```

I passed it to `UlamScreenMenu's` constructor like this:

```
UlamScreen::UlamScreen() : homeScreenMenu(homeScreenText) {

}

UlamScreenMenu::UlamScreenMenu(const char* menuText[], int length) {
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    _menuText[i] = menuText[i];
  }
}
```

I thought this would work, but for some reason, it does not. `tft.println(_menuText[i]);` used with `void drawMenu` does not send anything to my tft screen. When I use `tft.println(_menuText[i]);` from within the UlamScreen class it works perfectly.

Just to be clear, I can use the `tft` object within the `UlamScreenMenu` class because other functions like `tft.drawRect()` are working correctly.

What is wrong with this way of passing the `const char* []`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the reason you are not using the standard library types likes `std::string` and `std::vector`? Also `const char* _menuText[];` is not a valid declaration in standard C++

Comment: As an alternative to `std::vector`, see [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Pass a `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of a C-style array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you can't declare a member variable of type `const char* x[]`, since this would denote a flexible array member. Flexible array members are a C-feature allowing the last member of a struct to be an array of varying size (cf., for example, [Arrays of unknown size / flexible array members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array)). Having parameters of type `const char* x[]` in functions, however, is supported and has basically the same meaning as `const char** x`.

If you stick to a member of type `const char**`, then you'll have to handle memory management in that class. This means: take care of allocating, deallocating, copying, moving, copy-assigning, and move-assigning objets of that class (cf, for example, [the rule of 0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

If - as suggested in the comments - you use standard library collections, e.g. `std::vector`, these classes will do all this stuff in a reliable manner for you. See the following example illustrating the difference between both:

Note that the C++-version probably would not even take a `const char*[]`-parameter but directly a `const std::vector<const char*> &x`-parameter. But I kept the `const char*[]`-parameter in the constructor to provide the same interface in both variants:

```
// Variant 1: "old" C-style:
class Menu {
public:

    Menu(const char* x[], int length) {
        m_x = new const char*[length];
        m_length = length;
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            m_x[i] = x[i];
        }
    }

    ~Menu() {
        delete[] m_x;
    }

    // TODO: implement copy- and move constructors + copy- and move assignments
    // ...

    void print() {
        for (int i=0; i<m_length; i++) {
            std::cout << m_x[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    const char** m_x = nullptr;
    int m_length;
};

#include <vector>

// Variant 2: a C++- way:
class Menu2 {
public:
    Menu2(const char* x[], int length) {
        m_x.assign(x, x+length);
    }

    void print() {
        for (auto s : m_x) {
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Menu2 does not manage memory on its own, hence:
    // No special copy/move - constructors/assignments to be implemented.
    // No special destructor necessary
private:

    std::vector<const char*> m_x;
};

int main() {
    const char* x1[3] = {"one","two","three" };
    const char* x2[2] = {"eins","zwei" };

    // Variant 1
    Menu m1(x1, 3);
    m1.print();

    // Variant 2
    Menu2 m2(x2, 2);
    m2.print();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, it worked like a charm! I used the std::vector.